# fetchRequestTemplateForName: buggy?

Tags: macos, core-data, request, fetch

I have some simple fetch request templates saved in a data model in an OSX project. 
(OSx10.9 + Xcode 5.0.2)

If I create buttons and trigger the FR templates individually, they work fine. If I grab a dictionary of all fetch request templates, add all key names to a combo box, then use the combo.stringValue with model.fetchRequestTemplateForName then only the first one works.

I have NSLog() statements confirming that fetchRequestTemplateForName is being fed a proper string object with the FR template name.

Example - all of these work fine when suppling a literal string for the FR template name:

```
- (IBAction)btnTest:(id)sender {

// get a saved fetch request template from the managed object model

/*  // WORKS FINE
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest =
[self.managedObjectModel
fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"all_cars_under_15000"];
*/


/*  // WORKS FINE
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest =
 [self.managedObjectModel
 fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"audi_under_20000"];
*/

/* // WORKS FINE
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest =
 [self.managedObjectModel
 fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"all_white_cars"];

*/

 // WORKS FINE

NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest =
 [self.managedObjectModel
 fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"all_ford_cars"];


NSError * error = nil;

NSArray * resultsArray =
 [self.managedObjectContext
  executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


 // initialize and open the results window:
 if (resultsArray) {

  RW =
  [[ResultsWindow alloc]
  initWithWindowNibName:@"ResultsWindow"];

  RW.resultsArray = resultsArray;
 [RW showWindow:nil];
 }
}
```

Problem Code:

When I add these template names to a combo box then use the combo box to trigger and handle the fetch request, only one of the FR templates works, then the others bomb out with fetchRequest = nil

Example:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {

 NSDictionary * frDict = 
 [self.managedObjectModel fetchRequestTemplatesByName];
 NSArray * allKeys = frDict.allKeys;

  for (int i = 0; i < allKeys.count; i++){

    [self.cmbFetchRequests addItemWithObjectValue: allKeys[i]];

  }
 }





// self.cmbFetchRequests now has all stored FR templates

- (IBAction)cmbChangedStoredFetchRequest:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"%@", self.cmbFetchRequests.stringValue);


NSFetchRequest  * fetch =
 [self.managedObjectModel
 fetchRequestTemplateForName:self.cmbFetchRequests.stringValue];

/* tried this too:
NSFetchRequest  * fetch =
[[self.managedObjectModel
 fetchRequestTemplateForName:self.cmbFetchRequests.stringValue] copy];
*/


if (fetch) {

  // Create a new error object pointer:
  NSError * error = nil;

  // execute the fetch and deliver results to an array:
  NSArray * resultsArray =
  [self.managedObjectContext
   executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];


    // initialize and open the results window:
    if (resultsArray) {

    RW =
    [[ResultsWindow alloc]
    initWithWindowNibName:@"ResultsWindow"];


    RW.resultsArray = resultsArray;
    [RW showWindow:nil];
   }

  } else {
   NSLog(@"fetchRequest = nil !");
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that *should* be OK. The one thing I might try is using the object value in both places instead of creating the entries with object values and later using the string value to look up the request. That is, instead of `self.cmbFetchRequests.stringValue`, try `self.cmbFetchRequests.objectValueOfSelectedItem`.

Comment: Hi Tom, and thanks for the reply.Your suggestion worked, so I'm still not sure what's buggy and what's not. This code snippet works without crashing and a nil fetch request object:

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is either, but the change means that UI element data is out of the loop, that you're only using data looked up from the model. I'd have to take a close look at `stringValue` to see how it differed from `objectValueOfSelectedItem` to try and work out the real cause.

Comment: To be clear Tom, I hadn't tried objectValueOfSelectedItem, but I did perform variations of casts and object copies to get to the final string object that I was using with fetchRequestTemplateForName. It is stable now, but still worming away in the back of my mind! It may be connected to the same type of weirdness with predicates. In that you can parse and pass some string objects into a predicate string, but not the whole predicate! Go figure!?!?.